# How to remove whitespace from string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

Given this snippet:

```
require 'date'

raw_data = ["Mon\n                              9:00 -   1:00pm,   2:00 -   6:00pm",
 "Tue\n                            10:00 -   1:00pm,   2:00 -   7:30pm",
 "Wed\n                              9:00 -   1:00pm,   2:00 -   6:00pm",
 "Thu\n                              9:00 -   1:00pm,   2:00 -   6:00pm",
 "Fri\n                              9:00 -   1:00pm,   2:00 -   6:00pm",
 "Sat",
 "Sun"]

 raw_data.each do |element|
  a =  element.gsub(/\n/,',').gsub(/\s+/, '').split(',')

  day = a[0].to_s.downcase!
   "day: #{day}"

  map = { "mon" => "monday","tue" => "tuesday", "wed" => "wednesday", "thu" => "thursday", "fri" => "friday", "sat" => "saturday", "sun" => "sanday" }
  map.each {|k,v| day.gsub!(k,v) }

  day_from = a[1]
  day_from = day_from.to_s.split('-')[0]
  day_to = a[2]
  day_to = day_to.to_s.split('-')[1]
  day_to = day_to.gsub(/pm/,'')  unless day_to.nil?

  # not working??
  day_to = day_to.gsub(/\s+/,'') unless day_to.nil?
  p day_to
 end
```

How to get this output:

```
# desired
# "6:00"
# "7:30"
# "6:00"
# "6:00"
# "6:00"
# nil
# nil
```

Now this code returns:

```
#
# "  6:00"
# "  7:30"
# "  6:00"
# "  6:00"
# "  6:00"
# nil
# nil
```

google says to use:

```
  # not working??
  day_to = day_to.gsub(/\s+/,'') unless day_to.nil?
```

but this solution somehow does not work...

**UPDATE**

code with `hex code` and new input values

```
require 'date'
require 'hex_string'

raw_data = ["\n                            Mon\n                              8:30 -   6:00pm\n                          ",
 "\n                            Tue\n                              8:30 -   6:00pm\n                          ",
 "\n                            Wed\n                              8:30 -   6:00pm\n                          ",
 "\n                            Thu\n                              8:30 -   6:00pm\n                          ",
 "\n                            Fri\n                              8:30 -   6:00pm\n                          ",
 "\n                            Sat\n                              8:30 -   4:00pm\n                          ",
 "\n                            Sun\n                            10:00 -   3:00pm\n                          "

]

puts raw_data.size

 raw_data.each do |element|
  a =  element.gsub(/\n/,',').gsub(/\s+/, '').split(',')

  day = a[1].to_s.downcase!
  #puts  "day: #{day}"

  map = { "mon" => "monday","tue" => "tuesday", "wed" => "wednesday", "thu" => "thursday", "fri" => "friday", "sat" => "saturday", "sun" => "sanday" }
  map.each {|k,v| day.gsub!(k,v) }

  day_from = a[2]
  day_from = day_from.to_s.split('-')[0]
  day_from.to_s.strip unless day_from.nil?
  p "day regular: #{day_from}"
  p "day from(hex): #{day_from.to_hex_string}"
  p "-----------------------------------------"

  day_to = a[2].to_s.split('-')[1]
  day_to = day_to.gsub(/pm/,'')  unless day_to.nil?

  # not working
  day_to = day_to.gsub(/\s+/,'') unless day_to.nil?
  p "day regular: #{day_to}"
  p "day_to(hex): #{day_to.to_hex_string}"
  p "-----------------------------------------"
 end



"day regular:   8:30"
"day from(hex): c2 a0 c2 a0 38 3a 33 30"
"-----------------------------------------"
"day regular:   6:00"
"day_to(hex): c2 a0 c2 a0 36 3a 30 30"
"-----------------------------------------"
"day regular:   8:30"
"day from(hex): c2 a0 c2 a0 38 3a 33 30"
"-----------------------------------------"
"day regular:   6:00"
"day_to(hex): c2 a0 c2 a0 36 3a 30 30"
"-----------------------------------------"
"day regular:   8:30"
"day from(hex): c2 a0 c2 a0 38 3a 33 30"
"-----------------------------------------"
"day regular:   6:00"
"day_to(hex): c2 a0 c2 a0 36 3a 30 30"
"-----------------------------------------"
"day regular:   8:30"
"day from(hex): c2 a0 c2 a0 38 3a 33 30"
"-----------------------------------------"
"day regular:   6:00"
"day_to(hex): c2 a0 c2 a0 36 3a 30 30"
"-----------------------------------------"
"day regular:   8:30"
"day from(hex): c2 a0 c2 a0 38 3a 33 30"
"-----------------------------------------"
"day regular:   6:00"
"day_to(hex): c2 a0 c2 a0 36 3a 30 30"
"-----------------------------------------"
"day regular:   8:30"
"day from(hex): c2 a0 c2 a0 38 3a 33 30"
"-----------------------------------------"
"day regular:   4:00"
"day_to(hex): c2 a0 c2 a0 34 3a 30 30"
"-----------------------------------------"
"day regular: 10:00"
"day from(hex): 31 30 3a 30 30"
"-----------------------------------------"
"day regular:   3:00"
"day_to(hex): c2 a0 c2 a0 33 3a 30 30"
"-----------------------------------------"
```

Comment: Your code works as expected for me, with no extra spaces before "6:00", "7:30" etc. What ruby version are you using?

Comment: ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: hm strange, when I make this file executable and run it from console, I do get spaces...

Comment: works fine from the console using ruby 2.0.0p353 / OSX. Any odds you've an odd character in your file, e.g. an utf-8 non-breaking space, or something to that order, which is visually similar to a space or tab, but isn't getting caught by \s?

Comment: Works for me with both 1.9.3 and 2.0.0. Maybe you have a character in there that isn't really whitespace? What I copied and pasted from my browser may not accurately reflect what's in your file.

Comment: If I run it through xxd I see, for instance, `0000050: 2020 2032 3a30 3020 2d20 2020 363a 3030     2:00 -   6:00` with three spaces (20) before the "6:00" (363a 3030). If you get something different with your actual file on your actual system, there's your culprit.

Comment: Sean Redmond hm can you pls show me how to it?. I can share my real raw data as well..

Comment: If you're on a Unix(-like) system you probably have xxd available, and the command `xxd [filename]` will print out the bytes in the file in hexadecimal. Lots of code editors have a hex view as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have some non-breaking space characters in your file (`C2 A0` is the UTF-8 encoding for U+00A0, which is non breaking space).

In Ruby’s regular expressions `\s` doesn’t match non-breaking spaces, which is why your code doesn’t appear to work (`strip` also doesn’t remove them). You can use the [`\p{Space}` character property instead](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties), or the [POSIX bracket expression `[[:space:]]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes).

```
day_to = day_to.gsub(/\p{Space}/,'') unless day_to.nil?
```

or

```
day_to = day_to.gsub(/[[:space:]]/,'') unless day_to.nil?
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it's not working for you. I ran your script and it worked for me.

But you can try `strip`, which removes leading and trailing white spaces:

```
day_to.strip! unless day_to.nil?
```

Comment: hm was trying with `strip` as well, btw, when I use `strip!`, then I get `nils`